# Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My application were going well until some minutes ago, and now, it is printing this quite strange errror:

My imports are all right, I defined the managedBean name, and I don't know what it can be.

```
/login.xhtml @29,63 value="#{loginBean.participante.email}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
```

Here is the xhtml:

```
    <h:form id="formLogin">
                <p:dialog closable="false"
                          draggable="false"
                          visible="true"
                          minimizable="false"
                          resizable="false">
                    <h:panelGrid style="width: 300px">

                        <p:inputText id="email"
                                     value="#{loginBean.participante.email}"
                                     style="width: 100%"/>
              </p:dialog>
            </h:form>            
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

And here is my Bean:

```
package br.udesc.qiudesc.web.beans;

@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable{

private Participante participante;


@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    this.participante = new Participante();
}

public void login(){
    [login code]
}
```

}

Someone else had the same problem? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't you need an empty constructor? Also since you're using a `@SessionScoped` bean... then you should be using CDI, thus change `@ManagedBean (name="loginBean")` to `@Named` or the absence of `@ManagedBean` will default to `@Named`

Comment: you need to implement the getter and setter methods of participante.

Comment: Restart your web server, and try again.

Comment: @Cold it still wont work without a getter and a setter..

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan it's right, i'm think this is already done. And on other hand, the exception shows up that target is unreachable for Managed/CDI bean, and not for existence of property.

Comment: @Charles Ferrari what was the import you used for SessionScoped?

Answer (score 1):

A `public` getter and setter might help.

*For example:*

**A getter (accessor)**

```
public Participante getParticipante()
{
return participante;
}
```

**A setter (mutator)**

```
public void setParticipante(Participante participante)
{
 this.participante = participante;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good except you didn't declare `getter` and `setter` for `participante` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot for your help, I actually created the import for my object, but I needed to suppress a lot of code to fit here. I don't know what was actually happening, but, I rolled back my project and it worked again.

@J-con is right about using CDI, once javax.faces.bean is becoming obsolete, but it was not really the problem.

Thank you again,